# Can I safely move the /tmp partition or expand the /var partition on Ubuntu Linux if I have plenty of empty hard drive space?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

It's been several years since I was using Linux regularly.

When setting up my new computer a few months ago running Ubuntu, I followed an instruction guide that had me create separate partitions for efi, swap, root, boot, var, and tmp (in that order).

Because I had a 3 terabyte drive, I also added a FAT partition at the end of the disk, and left 1.3Tb unformatted / empty.

[image: Here's what that looks like in the Disks Tool]

Unfortunately, that lead to

**Problem:**  I dramatically underestimated how much space I would need in /var.

**Proposed Solution 1:**  First, move Partition 6, which is /tmp, further into the free space. Then, expand Partition 5, which is /var, to fill the remaining space.

**Proposed Solution 2:**  Create a new, larger, /var partition in the empty space as sd8, then copy /var over to that location and delete the original /var[sd5]

Will either of these solutions work, and if so, how do I go about it?

I'm assuming I need to be very careful with mounting and unmounting and permissions.  Do I need to boot a liveCD?

Or, if these don't work, what should I do?

Thanks!

PS, here's my current filesystem setup via terminal:

```
$ sudo df -h
[sudo] password for redacteduser: 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           6.3G  2.6M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       117G  6.2G  105G   6% /
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda4       4.6G  175M  4.2G   4% /boot
/dev/sda1       3.9G  7.9M  3.9G   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda3       1.1T  828G  216G  80% /home
/dev/sda6        23G   45M   22G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda5        23G   12G   11G  52% /var
/dev/sda7        58G   32K   58G   1% /dos
tmpfs           6.3G  904K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1000
```

And I'm running Groovy Gorilla

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=groovy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.10 (Groovy Gorilla)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.10"
VERSION_ID="20.10"
```

Comment: I'm afraid you were victim of inadequate advice (being nice here). There's no need for such complexity with partitions unless dealing with servers for very specific usages. Currently Ubuntu when installed automatically creates only 2 partitions: EFI and / (root). It uses swapfile by default instead of a separated swap partition as it used to be. A point can be mad for a separated /home but that's where the complexity ends for any regular user. It's probably easier to backup and install fresh the current 21.04 as support for 20.10 will end soon.

Comment: OMG.. I agree with @ChanganAuto .. 23 gigs mounted for temp is A BIT excessive.  ;)  Splitting them up isn't a problem (in fact gives more flexibility) but as ChanganAuto points out.. it adds needless complexity with very little return.  You will know when you need to go deeper with the mount points... because your previous choices will piss yourself off !! :)  Linux is very flexible.. very little you cant back yourself out of.

Comment: I was attempting to futureproof my system a bit as I dive back into linux.

I'm also intending to boot Windows, a different linux distro, and a Hackintosh version of OSK later (although now I'm thinking I'll just use different drives for them to make it simpler)

Answer (score 1):

Back up before you try anything. Ive come to learn the disk operations are fraught.

In theory, yes, you can just expand /var.  as it has empty space after it. The steps are to resize the partition and gave the OS reread it - best practice is to do this from a bootable disk so the filesystem is unmounted  but the brave/foolhardy among us might do it online.  Once the bock device is resized, reboot so the OS rereads the partition table and use resize2fs (or resize4fs depending on the distro - same tool) to expand the partition. Expanding partitions can be done online.

If you do rebuild your system, consider implementing LVM which inserts an abstraction layer making it a lot easier to do disk operations.  (Also  I generally find fewer partitions work better then multiple ones).

Lastly a guess and a hack which might help.  In my experience /var normally grows out of hand because of /var/log. If thats the case you may be able to fix the underlying problem by tuning logrotate. You can also create a new log directory on another mount point and then move /var/log to it, rmdir /var/log and ln -s /new/log/path /var/log  - Reboot or restart/ reload anything with an open log file (eg syslog).  This can fairly safely be done remotely with the risk being limited to your logs ,- assuming that is the cause of the issue.

Comment: - Thanks @davidgo  ---  I'm planning to do this from a liveCD.  -- Quick followup Q::  **What do I do with /tmp before expanding /var?**  

-

Comment: I misread. You can delete sda6 and recreate it at the end of sda5 - /tmp as long as you format it.  /tmp is considered transient and some distros delete its content on startup so nothing if value should be lost.  You should double-check that /etc/fstab is using sdX for mountpiint rather then UUID's